# Tengo un problema con esto Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=null}?

Tags: android

Tengo un problema a la hora de querer tomar fotos con la libreria Magical camera me bota este error

```
E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /external_storage_root/Android/data/com.example.d_app/files/Pictures/MagicalCamera/MagicalCamera: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.d_app, PID: 5370
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.example.d_app/com.example.d_app.addArt}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference
```

El codigo del OnActivityResult que utilizo para mostrar la foto en un Image View  es:

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    magicalCamera.resultPhoto(requestCode,resultCode,data);
    ivFoto.setImageBitmap(magicalCamera.getPhoto());
    String ruta =  magicalCamera.savePhotoInMemoryDevice(magicalCamera.getPhoto(),"nombre","carpeta",MagicalCamera.JPEG, true);
    Log.e("Ruta ",""+ruta);
}
```

Agradeceria que me ayudaran, gracias.
Los permisos los obtengo:

```
        String [] permissions = new String[]{
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
    };magicalPermissions = new MagicalPermissions(this,permissions);
```

Y tambien en el manifest

`public Bitmap getPhoto(){ return magicalCameraObject.getActionPicture().getActionPictureObject().getMyPhoto(); }`

Comment: El codigo es :    
´public String savePhotoInMemoryDevice(Bitmap bitmap, String photoName, String directoryName,
                                           Bitmap.CompressFormat format, boolean autoIncrementNameByDate) {
        return magicalCameraObject.getSaveEasyPhoto().writePhotoFile(bitmap,
                photoName, directoryName, format, autoIncrementNameByDate, magicalCameraObject.getActivity());
    }´
Pero de todas formas haciendo el debugg no llega hasta esa linea si no 1 mas arriba de esa y se cae

Comment: Ya está, pero el error es aca: magicalCamera.resultPhoto(requestCode,resultCode,data); llega a la data null

Comment: Vale, lo que pasa es que no tengo tantos detalles. Si el error es ahí entonces debes hacer las validaciones correspondientes para que cuando intentes buscar la imagen en la memoria no te explote, verificando si el archivo existe antes de obtener la imagen, ya sea cuando estés decodificando o haciendo operaciones con el Bitmap resultante, validaciones de `null` y lo demás. Si estás utilizando la camara del dispositivo vía `Intent`verifica que tengas los permisos para escritura y lectura externa, así como los de la cámara.